# What is the difference between LOG.error("IOException: " + e.getMessage(), e); and LOG.error("IOException: " +e.getMessage());?

Tags: java, logging, exception

I have observed that both the statements are valid. What is the extra thing logged in the first statement compared to the second one?

Comment: You can check that with LOG API.

Comment: First one has only cause(message). second has has both cause and throwable

Comment: Neither are valid, you need `()` after `getMessage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one also logs the original exception (and stacktrace), the second one only the message.

So, the 'extra thing' logged in the first statement is the original exception. This is generally a good thing to do, since this makes it easier to debug the error.

Comment: The Logger can be configured to log the stacktrace for example. Very useful at times.

Comment: In fact, the first form makes the inclusion of `e.getMessage()` as well as "IOException!" mostly redundant (that will be logged as part of the exception anyway). Better use the log message to give useful context, like what operation was being performed here, for which user, on which resource.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation

void    error(Object message) =>  Logs a **message** with error log level.

void    error(Object message, Throwable t) => Logs an **error** with error log level.

I think this might solve your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the method with throwable parameter the support team will be deeply grateful to you. The second one only prints the cause of the Exception, the first one shows the stacktrace.

If you use the second one inside a try / catch you probably are hiding the original Exception because it only prints the message of the first exception.